# Anonymous functions in Timer C#

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, label, anonymous-function

Why this is do not work?
I am do not understand what is here wrong . . .

```
  public static void Pause_ForCreate(out Timer _T,  ref Label _ChangeImageEllipse)
        {
            Label d = _ChangeImageEllipse;
            _T = new Timer(2000);
            // _T.Elapsed += EllipseVisible_Tick;
            _T.Elapsed += (sender, e) => EllipseVisible_Tick((object)d, e);
            _T.AutoReset = false;
            _T.Start();

        }
 private static void EllipseVisible_Tick(object Sender, ElapsedEventArgs E)
        {
           ((Ellipse)((Label)Sender).Content).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? As a note, you should always use a DispatcherTimer if you want to update UI elements.

Comment: `Why this is do not work?` please tell us what you want it to do.

Comment: I just want to change Visibility in this Ellipse like a "Visibility.Visible" but this is do not work . . . (

Comment: this is pretty complicated for what you want to achieve. You are using statics. Don't you have a `this` reference, or a page, or a window or some sort?

Comment: I have only these variables which is in function. Visibility is changing in Pause_ForCreate but when i send it to EllipseVisible_Tick Visibility is not changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a DispatcherTimer instead of a Timer, because its Tick handler is called in the UI thread (as opposed to an Elapsed handler of a Timer)

Then you don't need to pass the Label as `ref` parameter, because you don't want to change the reference inside the method. Also, since you are not returning anything you can remove the out from the `Timer _T`, and return the timer instead. The label `d`, is unnecessary and you can send the `_ChangeImageEllipse` directly to the `EllipseVisible_Tick` method, but since that method only does one small thing, the method might not be needed at all.

I would refactor it like this:

```
public static DispatcherTimer Pause_ForCreate(Label _ChangeImageEllipse)
{
    var t = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };
    t.Tick += (s, e) => _ChangeImageEllipse.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    t.Start();
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Project compiles but Visibility does not change.

Comment: @VitaliyAleksandrovich Because you must not modify a WPF UI element from outside the UI thread. A Timer Elapsed handler is called on a background thread. Use DispatcherTimer!

Comment: @Clemens  I am beginner . . . Can you show me how it will look at Tick ?

Comment: Like the Elapsed handler: `t.Tick += (s, e) => _ChangeImageEllipse.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;`

Comment: @Clemens You're right! Was just about to change to DispatcherTimer, but you were just ahead of me to do it yourself! :)